# set vi-style line editing interface in TCSH/CSH similar to "set -o vi" in bash

Tags: linux, bash, vi, csh, tcsh

in bash we can set vi-style line editing interface using `set -o vi`.
How to set the same in c-shell (tcsh or csh).

I tried `set -o vi`. but it throws error.

```
$>set -o vi
set: Variable name must begin with a letter.
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `bindkey -v`

[See this website](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix3/upt/ch30_14.htm)